# What would be the best word for a part of a recipe?

Tags: word-request

I'm not thinking of ingredients, more like components - i.e. it's what a glazing is to a cake.

What I mean is a part of a dish, not a part of the text of the recipe. The word I'm looking for is something like "half-product" but I was wondering if there's a term for that in cooking

Comment: A glazing is a glazing. Glazing/frosting are a category in baking.

Comment: You could generically refer to *glazing* as a *step* of the recipe.  Almost all written, itemized, instructions could be described as being composed of *steps.*

Comment: Component is probably the word you are looking for.  You already used it in your question.  Other possible synonyms are: part, piece, element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a generic word, other than component. E.g. this cupcake recipe has two components: the frosting and the cake.

Comment: One might also use the trm "element" or just "part" in place of "component" with much the same meaning.